# How to Generate a 3D Tetrahedral-Only Mesh in Gmsh?

Tags: mesh, finite-element-analysis, gmsh

I'm working with Gmsh to create a 3D mesh for a finite element analysis project using SfePy. My requirement is to generate a mesh consisting solely of tetrahedra, without the creation of intermediate edges or triangles. However, I'm encountering a challenge in configuring Gmsh to produce a mesh that meets this specification.

I've experimented with various Gmsh settings and scripting options to create a 3D mesh. Despite my efforts, Gmsh generates a mesh with edges, triangles, and tetrahedra. I need a mesh that consists only of tetrahedra for my analysis.
If I delete the edges and triangles from the mesh using delete module, the result of my finite element model would be different.

Is there a way to configure Gmsh to generate a 3D mesh composed exclusively of tetrahedra, without including any intermediate edges or triangles? If so, what are the specific settings or script modifications required to achieve this?

Any insights or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: well actually I found the solution by myself and I'm posting it here so other people benefit it too. if you use the gmsh module in python to convert your .geo file to a .mesh or .vtk file, you won't have any problems and your final mesh will be consisted of only tetrahedras!